# Associating Nested Object IDs in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

In my Spring MVC/JPA application I have User and Department entities defined in respect to their database tables. As a rule many Users can belong to one Department, so I have the following in my User Class

```
@Entity(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Username")
    private String username;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Department")
    private Department department;

}
```

When it comes time to save a new user I must associate the User with a Department's ID

```
User
username     | BobbySurfs2020
departmentId | 43
```

Do I ***need*** to have an additional `departmentId` field defined on my User object just to make this association, or can I somehow use the embedded Department object to set this ID via my setter `setDepartment()`?

**Update/Additional thought:**

Is it even necessary to have `Department` nested in the `User` object like I have here? I'm thinking it would take up more memory to store a  `Department` for every user I fetch than it would to associate *only* the `Department` ID's. That way if I needed a departments info at any time I could just simply look them up by the ID associated to the user. Thoughts?

Thanks much!

Comment: no you just add departmanId in user table in db after that just fetch departman via name and then set departman on user and save it also change Joincolumn(departman) with joincolumn(departmanid)

Comment: Thanks @mithatkonuk. I'm also thinking it might be necessary to store `Department` at all and use the ID instead

Comment: Thats because of orm relation you just give departman which stored in db thats way you can stay away complicated process anyway you can also use id in user class to set and save it can be also but im suggest to you this way will be more cool

Comment: By the way you can also use just departman has user list and user has no departman object unidirectional orm this way you can get rid of many departman object which same on different user

Answer (score 1):

*Do I need to have an additional departmentId field defined on my User object just to make this association.*

No

*Is it even necessary to have Department nested in the User object like I have here?*

Yes. You are using an **Object** Relational Mapper so map objects.

In the MVC world you can easily handle this by means of a converter which will take the ID passed from the UI, look up the relevant entity and set this on the Entity being edited.

```
@Component
public class StringToDepartmentConverter implements Converter<String, Department> {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentService service;

    /**
     *departmentId is the HTTP post param passed in by the framework
     */
    public Department convert(String departmentId ) {
        return  service.findDepartment(Integer.parseInt(departmentId ));
    }
}
```

Register this with the framework:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "..." })
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    //other configuration

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {
        formatterRegistry.addConverter(departmentConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public StringToDepartmentConverter departmentConverter(){
        return new StringToDepartmentConverter ();
    }
}
```